# VideoView problems in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-videoview

I have an app that has a header in the top portion of the app. Below the header it is a linearlayout that has a scrollview. Inside the scrollview I have a linearlayout with some scrollviews on it.

I can scroll the scrollview fine if the videos are not playing, but if the videos are playing, the videos overlaps the header of the app in an incredible android layout bug.

Can this be solved?

VideoViews stopped (works fine):

[image]

Scrolling down and videoviews playing (wrong behaviour):

[image]

Comment: try TextureView instead of VideoView

Comment: please give us your layout xml where you place your header view and scrollview

Comment: Might be when playing videos your videoviews are brought to front as they are focused. Try View.bringToFront() for views otherthan videos and see if it solves issue.